# Placing of jQuery initialization scripts with Ajax.BeginForm and partialView?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

In a partial view with an MVC Ajax.BeginForm, where should I ideally place javascripts like for assigning datepickers?
I realize that when I return PartialView("theview") everything before the BeginForm is also returned. So should I move the  inside the Ajax.BeginForm or what's it's best place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like setting datepickers etc that are modifying the form contents I would normally place just before the end of the relevant form.

Comment: If you also have a throbber img that belongs to the form, would you place that in the form or outside?

Comment: A spinning gif indicating ajax activity. :)